# Android: BLE clear cancel autoConnect

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my application I use auto connect to connect the BLE device as soon as it is available.

How I can cancel the autoConnect when I want

My Code for the auto connect:

```
bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(macAddress).connectGatt(this, true, callBack)
```

And how cancel it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just call disconnect() on the returned BluetoothGatt object.

If you don't need the BluetoothGatt object anymore, call close() to free resources in the Bluetooth stack.